# Is there a need to create interceptor again to update headers?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Android Studio 3.6

I have a http client (Retrofit 2.6) with header.

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
public class RestClientFactory {

  private static Interceptor headerInterceptor;
  headerInterceptor = chain -> {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        };
     httpClient.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor);
}
```

I need to update header "**Authorization**" after some event. To do this I use method `addHeader`:

```
 public static void addHeader(String tokenBackend) {
        headerInterceptor = chain -> {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", tokenBackend)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        };
    }
```

It's work. Nice.
But in method `addHeader`  I create `headerInterceptor`. Is it possible only to **UPDATE** current `headerInterceptor` ?

Comment: are you need to add header after login (some event)? or have to update header after create new token?

Comment: @RajasekaranM I need update after create new token

Comment: okay use Authenticator and update it

Comment: whats wrong with keeping the token header code under a if condition which will apply token only if it's available. Something like this                 if (usertoken != null) {
                    requestBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + usertoken);
                }

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA I added my answer. Is this is correct update of header? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191238/is-there-a-need-to-create-interceptor-again-to-update-headers/59192209#59192209

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this:

```
class BasicAuthInterceptor: Interceptor {

    private var mEncodedAuthorizationSection: String? = null

    private val authorizationHeaderValue: String
        get() = String.format("Basic %s", mEncodedAuthorizationSection)

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        var request = chain.request()
        if (canAttemptAuthorization()) {
            val requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue)
            request = requestBuilder.build()
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    fun setAuthorization(username: String?, password: String?) {
        if (username == null || username.isEmpty() || password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        val unencodedConcatenization = String.format("%s:%s", username, password)
        mEncodedAuthorizationSection = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedConcatenization.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }

    fun setAuthorizationValue(value: String?) {
        mEncodedAuthorizationSection = value
    }

    private fun canAttemptAuthorization(): Boolean {
        return mEncodedAuthorizationSection != null && !mEncodedAuthorizationSection.isNullOrEmpty()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Interceptor which has a token field which you update when a new one is generated.

```
public class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String tokenBackend;

    public TokenInterceptor(String tokenBackend){
        this.tokenBackend = tokenBackend;
    }

    public void setTokenBackend(String tokenBackend) {
        this.tokenBackend = tokenBackend;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", tokenBackend)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Then update your token this way.

```
private static TokenInterceptor tokenInterceptor = new TokenInterceptor("");
tokenInterceptor.setTokenBackend(tokenBackend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

Create **httpClient**:

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient;
private static String tokenBackend = "";
private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

 Interceptor headerInterceptor = chain -> {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            tokenBackend = ""
        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", tokenBackend)
                .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        };
        httpClient.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor);
```

And here update:

```
public static void updateHeader(String newTokenBackend) {
    tokenBackend = newTokenBackend;
}
```